# Recall and precision not working correctly(keras)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, sequential, precision-recall

I have to build a model in keras. I am really struggling with my actual dataset, hence I am just trying to figure out the basics on a simpler dataset.

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation="sigmoid"),
    Dense(2, activation="softmax"),
])
metrics=[ 
    tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives(name="tp"),
    tf.keras.metrics.TrueNegatives(name="tn"),
    tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(name="fn"),
    tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives(name="fp"),
    tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name="recall"),
    tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name="precision")
]

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=metrics, optimizer="sgd")
model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
evaluation = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
for i, m in model.metrics_names:
    print(m, evaluation[i])
```

This gets printed out:

```
loss 0.4604386021425058
tp 2965.5
tn 2965.5
fn 531.25
fp 531.25
recall 0.8480753898620605
precision 0.8480753898620605
```

Something really strange about this results. I believe it is due to using the softmax with two nodes.

y_train looks something like this:

```
array([[1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],

       [1., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

I tried a sigmoid, but then the whole model breaks down, at least here the fitting works.

Is there a way to configure recall and precision so they consider one output notes as Positive?

Comment: There seems to be a bug as you are using     `tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(name="fp")` instead of `tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives(name="fp")` to calculate the false positives.

Comment: Thanks, I made a typo. But the results remain the same after fixing it.

Comment: You can convert your train data into a one-dimensional array. For example [0,1] becomes 1, [1,0] becomes 0. Then you can convert your last dense layer into a Dense(1) and get the desired result. Otherwise, precision&recall is calculated for both class.

Comment: What do you mean by *whole model breaks down*? Indeed they are like this because of softmax.

Comment: @Frighter There is some keras error I don't understand, I will post it later.

Comment: @HakanAkgün is there any way to split the recall?

Comment: You can't use these metrics with 2-way softmax. One way would be the obtaining predictions after training and using sklearn to get recall-precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution in your case is to transform the problem into a one-dimensional one, i.e.

- Use `Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')` instead of `Dense(2,activation='softmax')`; change `[0,1]` to `0` and `[1,0]` to `1` as an example.
- Use `binary_crossentropy` instead of `categorical_crossentropy`.

Otherwise, you can implement a special callback to retrieve those metrics (using `scikit-learn`, like in the example below):

[How to get other metrics in Tensorflow 2.0 (not only accuracy)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60616842/how-to-get-other-metrics-in-tensorflow-2-0-not-only-accuracy/60800425#60800425)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this approach before and something went wrong than.

Comment: I still don't understand everything though. For example I have 120 examples in the test set. Yet the fp, tp, fn, tn numbers returned are 3064.000000, 33.000000, 551.750000, 68.000000. It looks they are cumulatively adding the numbers???